# Cannot push Ruby app to Heroku: App not compatible with buildpack, yet Gemfile exists

Tags: ruby, heroku

I've built a Ruby app for Twitter. I have a Gemfile and the Gemfile.lock that bundler created. This is the contents of the Gemfile

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'twitter'
```

When I try to push the app to Heroku, it fails with:

```
App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
```

I tried removing the buildpack from the Heroku settings. If I do this, it fails because it cannot detect the buildpack.

I can't see what is wrong here. Help gratefully received.

Comment: Are the `Gemfile` and the `Gemfile.lock` both tracked by Git? Are they both in the root of your repository?

Comment: Hi Chris. Yes, both in the root, and both tracked to git. Thanks

Comment: Are they both named _exactly_ like I show in my comment? Can you run `ls` (or `dir` if you're on Windows) from the root directory of your repository and add the result to your question as an [edit]?

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem. I'm rolling back your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a new line to the end of the gemfile